# TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable: Greedy Best First Search

Tags: compiler-errors

I am coding Greedy Best First Search Algorithm in Python, and this is the error that I am getting.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-7cb06a2b610d> in <module>
     41 source = 0
     42 target = 9
---> 43 best_first_search(source, target, v)

<ipython-input-4-7cb06a2b610d> in best_first_search(source, target, n)
     15 
     16         for v, c in graph[u]:
---> 17             if visited[v] == False:
     18                 visited[v] = True
     19                 pq.put((c, v))

TypeError: 'bool' object is not subscriptable
```

Greedy Best First Search is basically a combination of DFS and BFS using the PriorityQueue library i am trying to get the one with the lower score.
My code is:

```
from queue import PriorityQueue
v = 14
graph = [[] for i in range(v)]
 
def best_first_search(source, target, n):
    visited = [0] * n
    visited = True
    pq = PriorityQueue()
    pq.put((0, source))
    while pq.empty() == False:
        u = pq.get()[1]
        print(u, end=" ")
        if u == target:
            break
 
        for v, c in graph[u]:
            if visited[v] == False:
                visited[v] = True
                pq.put((c, v))
    print()

def addedge(x, y, cost):
    graph[x].append((y, cost))
    graph[y].append((x, cost))

    
addedge(0, 1, 3)
addedge(0, 2, 6)
addedge(0, 3, 5)
addedge(1, 4, 9)
addedge(1, 5, 8)
addedge(2, 6, 12)
addedge(2, 7, 14)
addedge(3, 8, 7)
addedge(8, 9, 5)
addedge(8, 10, 6)
addedge(9, 11, 1)
addedge(9, 12, 10)
addedge(9, 13, 2)
 
source = 0
target = 9
best_first_search(source, target, v)
```

Plz suggest a way to get the error out

Comment: `visited = True` needs to be removed.0

Comment: Thank you, the error is gone but there is still something missing since, i am not getting the desired output

Comment: 0 1 3 2 8 9  should be the output, but I am getting 0 1 0 3 2 8 9